# Are Daniell cells rechargeable (reversible)?

Tags: electrochemistry

I know that the Daniell cell is a primary cell and the reaction occurs as:

$$\ce{Zn -> Zn^{2+} + 2e^-}$$
$$\ce{Cu^{2+} + 2e^- -> Cu}$$

However, I do not know if we can reverse the reaction by applying a potential greater than $1.1~\mathrm{V}$. Also, please give the reason if it is not

P.S.: Please do not confuse this question: [Why can't a primary cell be recharged?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31329/why-cant-a-primary-cell-be-recharged)

I asked it as neither the above link nor the internet could give me satisfactory answer.

Comment: Daniel Cell is not a reversible cell. You can read the exact reason in Levine's Physical Chemistry book. I think it has something to do with the membrane separating the two halves of the cell.

Answer (score 5):

The Daniell cell is not rechargeable. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_cell#Chemistry):

> In the Daniell cell, the porous barrier cannot prevent the flow of
>   copper ions into the zinc half-cell. Hence, recharging (reversing the
>   current flow by an external source of EMF) is impossible because, if
>   the zinc electrode is made to become the cathode, copper ions, rather
>   than zinc ions, will be discharged on account of their lower
>   potential.

Answer (score 1):

A Daniell Gravity cell is reversible.  I just did the experiment and it worked.  I set up a cell with copper powder at the bottom and a zinc electrode at the top and filled the cell with zinc sulphate solution.  I applied 3 volts at 0.5 amps for a half hour and noticed that zinc plated onto the zinc electrode and copper was turning into a layer of blue copper sulphate solution at the bottom of the cell.  The cell produced 1.1 volts at .2 amps.

See attached photo:

[image]

Comment: In your image I can not see how you close the electrical circuit for your electrochemical cell. How did you do it?

Comment: My students usually find in the laboratory that if the $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions get in contact with a Zn electrode, they will start corroding right away. Guess your device relays on the very slow diffussion of the copper(II) ions during the experiment, but eventually the  ions will reach the Zn electrode. So we can not say the cell is rechargable.

Comment: Hi PAEP,  the copper powder at the bottom has a copper wire going to it and connected to the power supply as does the zinc.  You are correct that the copper plates out in the zinc.  It falls off back to the bottom so it will just turn back into copper sulphate when I recharge the battery.  The one trick is that I need to scrape the zinc electrode clean before recharging.  A selective anion exchange membrane between the top and bottom of the cell would take care of the  unwanted diffusion of copper.